# Getting wrong serial-port names from bluetoothdevice (c#)

Tags: c#, serial-port, bluetooth

To get all avaliable Serialports from the system i use the following command.

```
SerialPort.GetPortNames
```

It works fine for the mainboard serial port, but with the bluetooth device i get the wrong portnames.

For Example: Instead of COM7 i get sometimes COM70 or COM7ö. Its always 1 letter to much.

any suggestens?

PS: I am using newest Visual Studio Express in Windows 7 
PPS: The dirty hack to cut the last letter didn't work because i don't know which one is the bluetooth serial port (with various bluetoothstick or devices it changes the number of the comport) and after trying various sticks i reached COM10, ergo COM100 or COM10f

EDIT: the code i am using right now. reading the regestry, but still the same problem.

```
RegistryKey myRegistry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\\DeviceMap\\SerialComm");
foreach (string valuename in myRegistry.GetValueNames())
{
    if (myRegistry.GetValue(valuename) is String)
    {
        if (valuename.Contains("BthModem"))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(">" + myRegistry.GetValue(valuename) + "<" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally the second or third request is working with a result like

> COM11ᯋ<
>   COM10S<
>   COM11<
>   COM10<
>   COM11<
>   COM10<

how can that be?

Answer (score 2):

This has been [reported as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=236183) with non-null terminated strings:

Can you manually walk the registry?

```
HKLM\Hardware\DeviceMap\SerialComm
```

Comment: I get the values from the registry, but even there is only on Comport connected via bluetooth the registry is showing 2 Comports. Do you have any idea why thats happening?

Comment: Still same problem :( but normally the 3rd try is the right one. how could this be?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize WMI to query the system for serial ports, including those that are added by bluetooth devices and USB-To-Serial devices. Maybe that way you won't encounter this issue. See at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WMICodeCreator_Demo.aspx).

Comment: didn't work on my devenvironment. System.Managment could not be found. Maybe it's not part of express edition ??

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. SerialPort.GetPortNames basically uses the registry anyway- both of those methods don't seem to work with bluetooth.

The workaround I'm currently using is to loop through the first X com ports and see if they exist, which is hardly elegant. MS: FAIL.