# Odd SerialPort names which do not work

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

The Problem is simple, i am coding a tool which is able to connect GPS devices over the IO.Ports.SerialPort function in .NET

Everything works fine, but to list all available COM interfaces it looks like:

```
COM1  
COM2%  
COM3°
COM12$
```

its impossible to connect to a device which is called `COM3°`. If i simply try to connect manually to `COM3` it works perfect.

this is the code snippet which i am using right now:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count - 1
        cbbCOMPorts.Items.Add(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames(i))
Next
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Ahm, why don't you just use `cbbCOMPorts.Items.AddRange([System.IO.]SerialPort.GetPortNames())`?

Comment: Also, the function does lead down into the registry, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`, if those odd names are in there (which I believe), then there might be something wrong with your system or additional software altered those names.

Comment: This works, but the problem is still the same... I dont think that there is somethin wrong with my system, because this error appears on every PC I have tried!

Comment: EDIT: The devices are listed in the registry correctly...

Comment: @phil loh: Without the odd symbols? Now it's going to be nasty...is there anything odd about those systems or your Dev-System? Like not English OSs? And yes, I missed `Ports` in my first comment, sorry.

Comment: hmm, my OS is in german language...

Comment: @phil loh: In that case I'm out of ideas, sorry. You could try something like @Hans passant suggested. Remove the key in the registry and readd it, if the odd name is gone afterwards, then the Registry is screwed and regedit does not show it. Alternately you can also try to just overwrite the value.

Comment: This is a known bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522953/getting-wrong-serial-port-names-from-bluetoothdevice-c/2523404#2523404

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this before, it's been a while.  This is a bug in the driver, it is writing junk to the registry.  Bobby gave you the location, have a look-see with Regedit.exe.  Some kind of USB device, I imagine.  Throw it away and find another from a different manufacturer.  Cr*ppy drivers is not something you want to deal with.

Comment: hmm, i checked the location in regedit which bobby has written above. There are NO odd symbold, every COM Port is listed correctly...

Comment: It isn't always easily visible when the 0 string terminator is missing.  Use File + Export in regedit and have a look at the generated .reg file.  If that looks good, import it back in and try GetPortNames() again.  If it now works, you know that the driver is messing it up.

Answer (score 2):

Does the information at [this Connect MSDN post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/236183/system-io-ports-serialport-getportnames-error-with-bluetooth) help?

Specifically, I see this:

> Thank you for reporting this issue. The root cause of this (RegistryKey.GetValue fails to properly handle non-null terminated string data) will be fixed for the next version of the .NET Framework.
>
> Regards,
> Justin Van Patten

**Edit**: As noted in the comments above, this link and issue can be found in an [existing Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522953/getting-wrong-serial-port-names-from-bluetoothdevice-c/2523404#2523404).

Comment: Nice of them to fall on the sword.  But the real problem is that the driver is writing strings without zero-terminating them.  It's a classic off-by-one bug in C code when working with strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is another reason to use .Net 4.0 when using SerialPorts.  Probably the biggest issue is to fix USB SerialPorts being removed when the port is open, which leads to many problems (yeah, I know that the user isn't supposed to...).